# Can not locate menu with link after hovering on link for coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Currently I'm having issues returning either inner text or even links from a tool tip menu that displays after i hover over a link. Using dev tool I see that this link and the hover menu that appears in a Div labeled alphabetTooltip. Can anyone let me know if i'm going in the correct direction with this.

```
  public void get_All_Carousel_Cards_ofAlphabet() {
        //Mouse.Click(CarouselLinks);
        Mouse.Hover(CarouselLinks);
        HtmlDiv tooltipdiv = new HtmlDiv();
        tooltipdiv.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class] = "alphabetTooltip";
        HtmlControl controls = new HtmlControl();
        controls.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ClassName, "HtmlHyperlink");
        UITestControlCollection collection = controls.FindMatchingControls();

        foreach (UITestControl links in collection)
        {
         //cast the item to html hyperlink typ
            HtmlHyperlink mylinks = (HtmlHyperlink)links;
            //get the innertext from the link, which inturn returns the link value itself
            carousel_innerText = mylinks.InnerText;

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the tooltip as the parent for the hyperlink search as follows:

```
HtmlDiv tooltipdiv = new HtmlDiv();
tooltipdiv.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class] = "alphabetTooltip";
HtmlControl controls = new HtmlControl(tooltipdiv);
```

Comment: I had changed it to add that as the parent but it still couldn't find it for some odd reason.  here is what i had tried. HtmlHyperlink tooltip = new HtmlHyperlink();
            tooltip.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.TagName, "A");
            tooltip.SearchProperties[HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.TagName] = "A";
            HtmlControl controls = new HtmlControl(tooltip);

Comment: What's the error you get when trying to do an action on that HtmlControl?